# HTML element name issue in JS for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have some HTML `<p>` elements with ids `id="hex-1"`, `id="hex-2"`, etc.

Instead of manipulating them one by one (as follows) in my script file, I'm trying to use a for-loop.

```js
/* Code I'm trying to put in For-loop */ 
document.getElementById("hex-1").innerText = data.colors[0].hex.value
document.getElementById("hex-2").innerText = data.colors[1].hex.value
document.getElementById("hex-3").innerText = data.colors[2].hex.value
document.getElementById("hex-4").innerText = data.colors[3].hex.value
document.getElementById("hex-5").innerText = data.colors[4].hex.value
```

I've tried like as follows, but it's not working;

```js
/* Try 1 */
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  let hexCode = `hex-${1+i}`
  
  document.getElementById(hexCode).innerText = data.colors[i].hex.value
}

/* Try 2 */
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  let hexCode = "hex-" + (i+1)
  
  document.getElementById(hexCode).innerText = data.colors[i].hex.value
}
```

Comment: Should it be `data.colors.length`?

Comment: Please add the `data` Object you’re working with to your question.

Comment: Is data an array or an object? have you tried @DavidThomas's suggestion and in your for loop using **data.colors.length** and not **data.length**? In your for loop have you try **console.log(i)** to see if the loop is actually working?

Comment: @GreenGator can you update question with sample of data var?

Comment: Based on the shown code it has to be `data.colors.length` instead of `data.length` otherwise the `data.colors[i]` would not make sense.

Comment: @GreenGator Please try and spell things correctly; it's important in programming. `data.legth` is unlikely to work, as the property is spelled `length`. The other comments correctly spelled the desired property as `data.colors.length`, not `data.color.length`.

Comment: @GreenGator it doesn't show the data, it shows the word data. Post the contents of data, just not the word data.

Comment: Also, please don't use the snippet editor with code that doesn't run. Click "Run code snippet" and see what happens.

Comment: What happens when you add **console.log(i,data.colors[i].hex.value)**? in the for loop?

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas. I was so focused on the element id, I seem to have missed that. Your solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [**David Thomas**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) [mentioned in comments too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407823/html-element-name-issue-in-js-for-loop#comment129636412_73407823), It seems you should do something like:

```js
for(let i=0; i < data.colors.length; i++) {
  let hexCode = `hex-${1+i}`
  document.getElementById(hexCode).innerText = data.colors[i].hex.value
}
```

Comment: I edited your question to appropriately attribute the comment. Please do this yourself in the future.